# Spring security + session : Receive "Set-Cookie" header but not set in browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

I'm trying Spring Security & Session with an Angular front end.
I get a 200 code when trying to login with that response header :

```
Set-Cookie: SESSION=NGJlYTkzODQtNTQzMy00NGIxLWEzOWYtYTc2MGNlZWY1OTJm; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

But in my next request to the server, no cookie is automatically set in the request. And by the way, I cannot see the cookie in the developer tools so I think it's not saved.

I'm working in local for the front & back end.

Here are some info about the back end :

- using Spring MongoDb Session

  `@Configuration
  @EnableMongoHttpSession
  public class SessionConfig {
  }`

  - Classic Spring security Config

`
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

```
public SecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider) {
    this.authProvider = authProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic(); //todo csrf
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200")); // todo properties by environment
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

}
`

The session is well saved in the mongodb, just the id not saved in the browser.
Any idea ?

**edit**

When setting `observer: "response"` in the httpClient parameters, I cannot see the Set-Cookie header :

`"cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate,content-type: application/json,expires: 0,pragma: no-cache"`

But in the developer tool I have :

`HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: SESSION=YTEwOTNkNjAtZjI4MS00ZmM2LWExYmEtYzA5NzJhMjAyNTJh; Path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 11:25:08 GMT`

Comment: Try reading full response at angular side by passing option observe: 'response'

Comment: Set-Cookie is not in the array. I only have `"cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate,content-type: application/json,expires: 0,pragma: no-cache"`

Comment: Got it ! Thank you @Mrcode. I had to add the withCredentials parameter in angular side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue was in angular side !
I added an interceptor adding the withCredentials parameter and it works.

```
@Injectable()
export class XhrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const xhr = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });
    return next.handle(xhr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a CORS Filter in backend add this

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Date, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization, From, X-Auth-Token, Request-Id");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```